# Не возвращается переменная в методе C#

Tags: c#, массивы, методы

Здравствуйте сообщество!

Задуманно, чтобы метод maxim выдавал максимальное число в векторе, а переменная "maksik" возвращаемая.

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Ошибка    CS0127  Так как "Program.maxim(int[], int, int)" возвращает
> значение void, поэтому после ключевого слова return не должно
> присутствовать выражение объекта.

Часть кода:

```
static void maxim(int[]a, int n, int maksik)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                maksik = a[i];
                if (a[i] == a.Max()) a[i] = maksik;
                return maksik;


            }
        }
```

Подсвечивает красным return.

Если убрать название переменной и просто оставить return, то будет выведен полностью массив, а не один элемент.

Полный код:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace work_17
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void maxim(int[]a, int n, int maksik)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                maksik = a[i];
                if (a[i] == a.Max()) a[i] = maksik;
                return maksik;


            }
        }
        static void one(int[]a, int n) // Переставить первый и максимальный элемент вектора
        {
            
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int maksik = a[i];
                if (a[i] == a.Max())
                {
                    a[i] = a[0];
                    a[0] = maksik;

                }
            }
        }
        static void two(int[]a, int n)
        {

        }
            
        static void Print(int[]a) // выводит вектор на экран
        {
            foreach (int elem in a)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", elem);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        static void Input(int[]a, int n) // формирует массив
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                a[i] = rnd.Next(-100, 100);

            }
        }
        static void four(int[] a, int n)
        {
            int mx, mn;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] == a.Max())
                {
                    mx = a[i];
                }
            }
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args) // Главный метод
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите количество элементов векторов (столбцов для матрицы): ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите количество строк матрицы: ");
            int j = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] m = new int[n];
            int[,] mm = new int [n, j];
            Input(m, n);
            Console.WriteLine("Изначальный вектор: ");
            Print(m);
            one(m, n);
            Console.WriteLine("Меняем местами максимальный элемент с первым....");
            Print(m);
            Console.WriteLine("Максимальное число: ");
            maxim(m, n);
            Print(m);
            //two (m, n);
            //Print(m);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Не судите строго, я новичок в C# и вообще в программировании.

Comment: И да, я знаю, что метод one уже его находит, надо чтоб ещё один метод находил просто максимальный элемент и выводил его одним числом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно `void` заменить на `int`, чтобы сказать методу что именно оно будет возвращаемым типом. А также в конце метода придётся дописать какой-нибудь `return 0`, чтобы вернуть значение `int`-a, иначе его будет не хватать. Так вы обозначаете, что данный метод результатом своей работы вернет (отдаст обратно,в место своего вызова) значение с типом данных `int`.

Comment: Теперь подсвечивается само название метода после int и выдаёт ошибку:

Ошибка CS0161 "Program.maxim(int[], int, int)": не все пути к коду возвращают значение.

Comment: Я написал что нужно сделать. Прочитайте ответ ещё раз **до конца**

Comment: @e.shikhanov такая ошибка возникает если retrun стоит внутри if-a или for-a. В общем любого оператора, который может не исполниться